# Trying to read an mp3 file in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am looking a read an mp3 file currently located in my public folder.

I have tried the following:

```
2.5.3 :016 >     audio_file = File.new('/demo.mp3', 'rb')
```

And it resulted with the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
        3: from (irb):16
        2: from (irb):16:in `new'
        1: from (irb):16:in `initialize'
Errno::ENOENT (No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - /demo.mp3)
```

I would assume this is pretty straight forward but for some reason it does not work. Does anybody knows how to do that ?
Alternatively, would it be possible to read a file that is located in a server via an `http://xxxxxxx.xxxxx/xxxx/mp3` for example ? (This is where the file is located initially).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got the wrong path. `/demo.mp3` will look for the file at the root of your file system.

If it's in `public/`, then you need to specify the path using the relative path `public/demo.mp3` since the app is running from the project folder (supposedly) which contains the `public/` folder.

Comment: Thank you! Cannot believe I still make these kind of mistakes. Do you know by any chance if it is possible retrieve an audio record from a weblink directly so I do not have to manually download the file first to my public folder ?

Comment: @Etienne you can use `open-uri` gem for reading files from weblink directly

Comment: Hi Sumanth, I managed to open indeed, thank you. I am not at the next issue :)

Answer (score 1):

You can also use path `"#{Rails.root}" + "/public/demo.mp3"`

Comment: `Rails.root` is a `Pathname`, so you could also do `Rails.root.join('public/demo.mp3')` or even `Rails.root.join('public', 'demo.mp3')`.